# XPath : Get attribute value if it is blank or not

Tags: xpath

I have an html data like below

```
<select>

<option value="1" disabled="disabled">1</option>
<option value="2" disabled="disabled">2</option>
<option value="3" disabled>3</option>
<option value="2" disabled="disabled">2</option>
<option value="3" disabled>3</option>

</select>
```

I'm using this xpath selector

```
//select/option///@disabled
```

This selector returns 3 disabled text like this:

```
disabled
disabled
disabled
```

But I want is selecting all options disabled value what ever they has a value or not, some thing like this

```
disabled
disabled
NULL
disabled
NULL
```

or some thing like this is also acceptable

```
true
true
false
true
false
```

is this possible by xpath selectors?

Comment: You might want to add some information about the environment in which you use XPath against HTML because I think, given the input is not XML, it depends very much on how the HTML is parsed into a tree and how XPath operates on that tree to be able to tell whether XPath can help distinguish or identify all the given disabled options.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use this one:

```
//select/option/not(@disabled = '')
```

Result should be

```
true
true
false
true
false
```

Comment: I don't know why, but it didn't worked for me. I'm trying by XPATH Helper : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl

Comment: I've double-checked with http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi and it still works fine...This migth not work with `XPath` checkers that expect to get `xml` only as source because in `xml` attribute must have some value, e.g. `disabled=''` unlike in `html` where it can be just `disabled`

Comment: yes, may be it is about html parsing. I have checked it with scrapy (Python) no way, it doesn't ork.